# I just got the 14.04 and can't get my wifi

Tags: wireless

I just signed up for the 14.04 and I have wifi in my home and office but I can't log in to either on the laptops or desktops. Please help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Does it show any available wifi connections on the top right of the screen?
If not, you need to install your wireless drivers, if you need a internet connection to download them, wire your computer to the router until everything is installed.

Comment: okay so after I put the router to my computer do I have to leave it plugged in or can I take it out after a while?

Comment: you leave it plugged in until you don't need the internet anymore, basically you plug it in, find your wireless driver on the internet, install it, then you should be good to go. Also, Go to System Settings>Software & Updates, And click the Additional Drivers tab, if there is a default wireless driver enabled, try disabling it, it worked for me in ubuntu 13.04